# E/MS_RegisterService: Exception getting GCM token java.io.IOException: TIMEOUT

Tags: java, android

New to android development.
I encountered this problem while I was trying to test my "history" activity
Have no clue what and how to do with it.
I searched for some answers but they are all beyond me so I'd have to post mine up.
And I also keep getting this error in logcat:
"E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module"
Don't know how to solve it either
Thank you guys in advance.

This is the OnclickListener

```
findViewById(R.id.view_history_button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent toHistory=new Intent(main,history.class);
            main.startActivity(toHistory);
        }
    } );
```

This is the code of "history" activity

```
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class history extends AppCompatActivity {
public ListView listView = null;
private List<Map<String, Object>> list = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();
private SimpleAdapter simpleAdapter = null;
private String date;
private String target;
private String item;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_history);
   listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview) ;
    simpleAdapter= new SimpleAdapter(this,getdata() , R.layout.listview_content,
            new String[] { "date","target","item"}, new int[] { R.id.time ,R.id.name,R.id.item});
    listView.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);

}
private List<Map<String, Object>> getdata() {
    DBHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper(getApplicationContext(),
            "Delivery_info",null,1);
    SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor=db.rawQuery("select * from info_table",null);
    if(cursor.moveToFirst() ){
        while(!cursor.isAfterLast())
            date = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("date"));
            target = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("target"));
            item = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("item"));
            Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            map.put("date", date);
            map.put("target", target);
            map.put("item", item);
            list.add(map);
       // }
    }
    return list;
}
}
```

And this is the Manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.android.robottracking">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".splash">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".task" />
    <activity android:name=".history" />
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"></activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

and this is the screenshot of the logcat
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uym8C.png)

Comment: Please post the full stack trace of the exception (`printStackTrace()` output)

Comment: sry i didnt write printStackTrace method originally, I'll start writing it into the activity and see what it's gonna report, but I'll post the logcat screenshot though

Comment: is this logcat from your app? Looks like from the GSM client